# Unable to run tmux on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, shell, tmux

So I got brew on my mac and I had tmux installed and running just fine. Then after I refreshed my system every time I try to run tmux i get this error:

"-bash: tmux: command not found"

So since I'm kinda new to linux or unix based systems in general I'm having problems getting it to work. I got "tmux.conf" file in place but that doesn't seem to help.

Any takers on this one?

**UPDATE:**

per request from the comments.

```
echo $PATH
```

gives me

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

*brew* command also works

Comment: First run a "locate tmux" from the command line to see if the binary is installed. You may need to update the locate database if you haven't ran that command before.

Comment: So I ran "locate tmux" and it told me that the database didn't exit in /var/db/locate.database
I ran 
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
to create it and it took it but then I ran locate tmux again and it gave me the same thing that the database wasn't created yet..

Comment: Oh.. apparently it created the database after a while.. but now what do i do?

Comment: Does the `brew` command work? What's the output of `echo $PATH`? Please [edit] the question and include that info.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refreshed my system'? brew should usually install things and link them in /usr/local/bin. Try `brew list tmux`. If it's installed, it'll show up. If it shows up but you can't find tmux in /usr/local/bin/ try `brew link tmux`

Comment: So I ran     brew list tmux and     brew link tmux and now when I try to start it I'm getting     -MacBook-Pro:~ ldimans$ tmux
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tmux
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
I checked the path and the lib is not there. Have no idea where it went

Comment: It's possible that libevent isn't fully linked. Try `brew unlink libevent` and `brew link libevent`.

Comment: So I did that and now when I try to run tmux it says [exited] and nothing happens.. I tried googling it but that didn't help..any ideas?